# crystal report: crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports

How can i embed text object inside my crosstab row section?

Another work around:
how can i add subreport embedded inside the crosstab?

my goal is, i used the crosstab to generate dynamic columns. 
but the detail section, i need more control.
Tommy

Answer (score 0):

> How can i embed text object inside my
>   crosstab row section?

Your best option is to create a formula and add that formula as a grouping.

> Another work around: how can i add
>   subreport embedded inside the
>   crosstab?

This can't be done.

Comment: That's was what i thought too, use one formula to create multiple rows on a cell, however,this way, it is very hard to lineup the corresponding items on the summarized cell. especially the summarized cell has alternative row color.

Comment: oops more
my structure
     COLUMN  COLUMN  COLUMN
ROW:
text1     2
text2     3 
text3     4
ROW
text1     2 
text2     4
text3     8